# Парсер не читает документ

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Пишу парсер xml(больше 18к строк) на Python. Скрипт качает документ, но не может открыть из-за проблемы с кодировкой(как я понял). Если вручную открою скачанный xml и сохраню с кодировкой UTF-8 WITH BOM, то программа все читает и работает.

```
import wget
from lxml import etree

def parseBookXML(xmlFile):
    wget.download(xmlFile, 'C:\\Users\\Cplasplas\\Desktop\\XML-PARSER\\urls.xml')
    Files = open('urls.xml')
    Files.close
    File = 'urls.xml'
    with open(File, encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
        xml = fobj.read()

    root = etree.fromstring(xml)

    book_dict = {}
    books = []
    rootAttr = root.attrib
    counter = 0

    for offer in root.getchildren():
        print(offer.attrib)


    return books


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseBookXML("something.xml")
```

### ПРОБЛЕМА РЕШЕНА! with open(File, 'rb') as fobj: ПИШИТЕ rb вместо utf-8

Comment: Зачем это `Files = open('urls.xml')` `Files.close`?

Comment: А так работает `with open(File, encoding='utf-8-sig') as fobj:`?

Comment: @gil9red нет( Files = open('urls.xml') Files.close это чтобы открыть и сразу закрыть

Comment: !) нет смысла в этом 2) закрытия не будет, т.к. закрывать нужно так `Files.close()`. Без скобок функция не вызовится. А что не работает? Есть ли ошибка или что?

Comment: @gil9red Проблема решена! with open(File, 'rb') as fobj: вот что нужно было :) "rb"

Comment: `rb` означает, что файл будет считываться без кодирования, т.е. байтами, тогда, в этом случае парсер `lxml` сам должен понять с какой кодировкой имеет дело. Возможно, там была не `utf-8` кодировка (с bom или нет). Оформите это в виде ответа, раз вам помогло :)